# Alert if 2 for loop are executed

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I would like my script launches alert if my two loops is done correctly. This is a sort of check validation script that each field is full, but this script execute the second loop at the same time as the first, so I want an alert if all input. argument are filled after everyone was able to be checked one by one. http://jsfiddle.net/thybomoon/4dvw6/5/

```
$(document).on('click', '#Check', Check);

function Check() {
    var length_PA = $('#PA .argument').length;
    for (i = 1; i < length_PA + 1; i++) {
        var val_PA = $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").val();
        if (val_PA === "") {
            $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").css('background', 'red');
            break;
        } else if (val_PA !== "") {
            $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").css('background', 'green');
        }
    }
    var length_CA = $('#CA .argument').length;
    for (i = 1; i < length_CA + 1; i++) {
        var val_CA = $("#CA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").val();
        if (val_CA === "") {
            $("#CA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").css('background', 'red');
            break;
        } else if (val_CA !== "") {
            $("#CA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").css('background', 'green');
        }
    }
 alert('alert me');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It necessary to know if for loop are executed and it's possible like that :

```
$(document).on('click', '#Check', Check);

function Check() {
    var length_PA = $('#PA .argument').length;
    var count_PA = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < length_PA + 1; i++) {
        var val_PA = $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").val();
        if (val_PA === "") {
            $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").focus();
            break;
        } else if (val_PA !== "") {
            $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").css('background', 'green');
            count_PA++;
        }
    }
    if (count_PA == length_PA) {
        var length_CA = $('#CA .argument').length;
        var count_CA = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < length_CA + 1; i++) {
            var val_CA = $("#CA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").val();
            if (val_CA === "") {
                $("#CA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").focus();
                break;
            } else if (val_CA !== "") {
                $("#CA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").css('background', 'green');
            count_CA++;
                if(count_CA == length_CA) {alert('done');}
            }
        }
    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thybomoon/4dvw6/10/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `break;` from your `if` condition

```
 if (val_PA === "") {
     $("#PA tr:eq(" + i + ")").find(".argument").css('background', 'red');
     //break; //remove it
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rameshcharykotha/4dvw6/8/)

Comment: Deleting the break does not go in the direction I want. I myself can be misspoke and I apologize. I would like to receive an `alert` once all the `input` will be checked and busy. Before, I do not want ..

Comment: once all the input will be checked and busy. Before, I do not want. What do you mean by this.

Comment: I suggested an answer, I just thought, you know me?